# 1TB word (1-gram) corpus

Tags: corpora, resource-request

**Where can I find a 1TB or larger 1-gram corpus?**

I am comparing certain structures for term-frequency calculation, but without a significantly large dataset I won't be able to show the non-theoretical speed gains.

Comment: how many words is 1TB?

Comment: 1TB seems like a lot. Does it have to be entirely in one language?

Comment: @jlovegren 1TB = 10^12 bytes = normally 5*10^11 or 10^12 characters depending on encoding

Comment: prash: Well all I am measuring is term-frequency, so I suppose language would be irrelevant.

Comment: Wikipedia will give you around 15GB, and Gutenberg around 5-10GB

Answer (score 2):

Mark Davies' [version of the Google Books corpus](http://googlebooks.byu.edu/compare-googleBooks.asp) (has more functionality than the Ngram viewer) has 155 billion words, which is getting close to 1TB.

Answer (score 1):

Are [the corpora available from Google Books Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets) not the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking at that earlier, it's 1-gram are only in the 10s of GB range. I mean, I could work with larger 2-gram and 3-gram... and could also split them up into 1-gram...

Comment: I was looking for their 1TB corpus which I knew about vaguely I while ago and don't know if this is what they call it now or if that's another thing \-: